# Trouble with the nmds_phyloseq function of the phylosmith package: Error in `stat_ellipse()

Tags: r, phyloseq

I am using the phylosmith package to make ordination plots from my phyloseq file (microbial ecology data).

Here's the command:
nmds_phyloseq(pseq, c("Description"), circle = TRUE, verbose = FALSE)

I get the error:
Error in `stat_ellipse()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `compute_layer()`:
! `stat_ellipse()` requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

> rlang::last_trace()
> <error/rlang_error>
> Error in `stat_ellipse()`:
> ! Problem while computing stat.
> ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
> Caused by error in `compute_layer()`:
> ! `stat_ellipse()` requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y

Backtrace:
▆

1. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(x)
2. └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
3. ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
4. └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
5. ```
   └─ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
   ```
6. ```
     ├─rlang::try_fetch(...)
   ```
7. ```
     │ ├─base::tryCatch(...)
   ```
8. ```
     │ │ └─base (local) tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
   ```
9. ```
     │ │   └─base (local) tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
   ```
10. ```
      │ │     └─base (local) doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
    ```
11. ```
      │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
    ```
12. ```
      └─ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
    ```
13. ```
        └─l$compute_statistic(d, layout)
    ```
14. ```
          └─ggplot2 (local) compute_statistic(..., self = self)
    ```
15. ```
            └─self$stat$compute_layer(data, self$computed_stat_params, layout)
    ```
16. ```
              └─ggplot2 (local) compute_layer(..., self = self)
    ```

I really don't understand what is not working here. I tried giving values to x and y, without success. (It tells me Error in nmds_phyloseq(pseq_relab, c("Description"), x = 1, y = 2, circle = TRUE,  :
unused arguments (x = 1, y = 2))

The pcoa_phyloseq function of the same package works perfectly on my data (code below)
pcoa_phyloseq(pseq, c("Description"), x = 1, y = 2, method = 'bray',
circle = 0.95, colors = colours, labels = NULL)

Any idea of what is going wrong and how I could solve this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.